# C# How to get Words From String

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, string, words

Hi guys i was trying a lot to retrieve some other strings from one main string.

```
string src = "A~B~C~D";
```

How can i retrieve separately the letters? Like:

```
string a = "A";
string b = "B";
string c = "C";
string d = "D";
```

Comment: begin with string.Split and then trim chars you want to get rid of.

Comment: Anything special about `~` and what have you tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one. It will split your string with all non-alphanumeric characters.

```
string s = "A~B~C~D";
string[] strings = Regex.Split(s, @"\W|_");
```

Answer (score 16):

you could use `Split(char c)` that will give you back an array of sub `string`s seperated by the ~ symbol.

```
string src = "A~B~C~D";

string [] splits = src.Split('~');
```

obviously though, unless you know the length of your string/words in advance you won't be able to arbitrarily put them in their own variables. but if you knew it was always 4 words, you could then do

```
string a = splits[0];
string b = splits[1];
string c = splits[2];
string d = splits[3];
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this

```
string src = "A~B~C~D"
//
// Split string on spaces.
// ... This will separate all the words.
//
string[] words = src .Split('~');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
string src = "A~B~C~D";

string[] strArray = src.Split('~');

string a = strArray[0];   
string b = strArray[1];   
string c = strArray[2];
string d = strArray[3];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string src = "A~B~C~D";
string[] letters = src.Split('~');

foreach (string s in letters)
{
    //loop through array here...
}
```

Comment: Oops - need to type faster I think.  5th answer posted by the time I pressed submit :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider...

```
string src = "A~B~C~D";
string[] srcList = src.Split(new char[] { '~' });
string a = srcList[0];
string b = srcList[1];
string c = srcList[2];
string d = srcList[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string words[]=Regex.Matches(input,@"\w+") 
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(x=>x.Value)
                    .ToArray();
```

---

`\w` matches a single word i.e A-Z or a-z or `_` or a digit

`+`is a quantifier which matches preceding char 1 to many times

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen he has edited his question ...his initial question was to select all the **words** from string.

Comment: omg, thank you guys :O So many answers in such a short time. WOW !! I've never seen something like this :))

Answer (score 1):

I like to do it this way:

```
        List<char> c_list = new List<char>();
        string src = "A~B~C~D";
        char [] c = src.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char cc in c)
        {
            if (cc != '~')
                c_list.Add(cc);
        }
```